# multiple update records with one button

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, dreamweaver

i use "php do" and "php while" to display all record.
and each record have buttons which is "update record", i trying to do the one button to make those records update.
all i need is only one button to update them, anyone can help me to make it?

this is the code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/tlsc_conn.php'); ?>
<?php
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tb_exam SET answer1=%s, answer2=%s, answer3=%s, answer4=%s, correct=%s WHERE question_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['answer1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['answer2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['answer3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['answer4'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['correct'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['question_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_tlsc_conn, $tlsc_conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $tlsc_conn) or die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database_tlsc_conn, $tlsc_conn);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM tb_exam";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $tlsc_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       function myFunction()
{
alert("Record has been updated!");
}
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
.style13 {color: #000000}
.style12 {color: #FFFFFF}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php do { ?>
    <form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table align="center">
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right">Question_id:</td>
          <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['question_id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="correct" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" size="32">
          <input name="answer1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer1']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer2']; ?></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="correct" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer2']; ?>" size="32">
          <input name="answer2" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer2']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer3']; ?></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="correct" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer3']; ?>" size="32">
          <input name="answer3" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer3']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer4']; ?></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="correct" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer4']; ?>" size="32">
          <input name="answer4" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['answer4']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right">Correct:</td>
          <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['correct']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
          <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update record" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1">
        <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['question_id']; ?>">
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```